# How to calculate total work & break hours from logins and logouts in excel?

Tags: excel, authentication, logout

I need to calculate the total work hours and break hours of each employees from their Logins and Logouts. In excel sheet i am having hundreds of login and logout record of employees in the format mentioned below (image). I need a way to calculate the working hours and break hours.
Any help would be appreciated.

[Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hlDg.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

**Your question is a bit broad but I will have a go at answering it in it's current state:**

Where E2 is the ID:

`=SUMIFS($B$2:$B$7,$C$2:$C$7,"Logout",$A$2:$A$7,E2)-SUMIFS($B$2:$B$7,$C$2:$C$7,"Login",$A$2:$A$7,E2)`

This is a simple total time of logouts minus total time of logins, this will work assuming there are equal number of Logins vs Logouts.

[image: example]